# Centos7 extras and rhel7 extras missing packages issue

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, centos7, rhel7

I am merging ansible into our internal RHN satellite.  I have a fully updated RHEL 7 base repo, extras, supplementary, optional, and RHN tools from Red Hat.
I have also merged selected packages into a epel repo when we need them.  This for example is where ansible is going to live.

In centos7:

`python-crypto x86_64 2.6.1-1.el7.centos  extras  470 k
 python-ecdsa  noarch 0.11-3.el7.centos   extras  69 k`

These 2 packages are dependencies for ansible and are in the extras repo for centos7.  They are however missing from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 extras.

I was always under the impression that there would not be packages offically released from Centos that would not also be offically released from Red Hat.

My issue is that I don't want to put this in my epel repo cause it's not epel.  This is first time that I have ever experienced that there are packages offered by centos that are not a part of the corresponding Red Hat distribution. Version differences I can understand, but a missing package seems odd to me.

Is this an error?  Should this not happen?

Comment: There is a list of packages addition/change/deletions on https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7#head-d58ad86f1b5399bb36755532321b1df4f242a88c, but that's the base packages. Still, there are some changes. Would be interesting to see how this works for extras.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved this question to serverfault, I think the question is probably better suited to be there.

https://serverfault.com/questions/728307/centos7-extras-and-rhel7-extras-missing-packages-issue